# Debugging with Xcode 13.4 hanging forever

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints, xcode13

Do you also have any difficulties while debugging with **Xcode 13.4**. Most of the time it **hanging/stuck** at break point. I always have to stop(need to hit stop button at least 10 to 12 times) and run again. Even though I do that, same thing happens over and over.

And also most of the time it is unable to expand the data at breakpoint to see what's in there.

I tried to clear `DerivedData`, to restart the Xcode, to close apps in Mac with high memory usage and so on. But nothing help.

It would be really nice if you can share your solutions for the similar issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if you have a `Hide Window Tab Bar` in `View` menu? In order to fix Xcode slowness, I had to hide them.

Comment: I am facing similar issue and not able to debug using Xcode 13.4. It reaches to first breakpoint, but when I do stopover, it hangs. This is happening every time for me, not able to see data even a single time.

Comment: "This is happening in closure. before closure it is working."

Comment: I am using Xcode 13.3.1 and this just started happening to me in a project that had been working fine. I also see that it seems to only happen in a closure.

Comment: I have the same problem with 13.4 and 13.4.1.

Comment: I have the same problem, is there any solution?

Comment: I had the some problem. It went away after installing xCode 14 but instead I got the issue of compile errors vanishing as soon as they appear.

Comment: With Xcode 12.4 on Catalina this happens for many breakpoints, but not all.  When it happens it never finishes loading the variables view, and I have to terminate the process.  I see the problem frequently, not always in closures.  I'm not seeing the problem with Xcode 14.2 on Monterey.